# Laravel 5 sending mail to multiple users at once

Tags: laravel, email, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am trying to sending mails to all users. But i can't figure out how to make this. In my controller, i made this.

```
public function send_mail()
{
    $mails = Joinus::all();
    $array = array();
    $allmails = array();
    foreach ($mails as $mail)
    {
        $allmails = array_push($array, $mail->email);

    };
    Mail::to($allmails)->send((new SendMail(new Joinus('email')))->delay(30));
}
```

I am getting all types of error. Last one is

```
__construct() must be of the type array
```

In my SendMail.php

```
public function __construct($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}
```

I wasted my one day and can't make. I am very grateful for your help. Thanks an advance.

Comment: you need to be more specific abt all types of errors.

Comment: If you get all sorts of errors a good place to start is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: Please check my below answer.

Comment: If you don't want all recipients of your email to see all other email addresses, you should consider using `Mail::bcc($emails)->send(...)` instead of `Mail::to($emails)->send(...)`. And if you have the requirement that each recipient gets an individual link in the email (like a registration link), you'll have to send one mail per address anyway - meaning none of the above solutions will work.

Comment: When i said all king of errors. I mean i worked a lot. But there is no code here right now. This is the last thing i made. 
Errors are about mailing system. I just don't know how to send bulk mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$allmails = array_push($array, $mail->email);` is wrong

Right answer is just `array_push($array, $mail->email);`

`array_push($array, $mail->email);` this is returning an array.

`$allmails = array_push($array, $mail->email);` 
But this is returning int value.

Answer (score 4):

```
public function send_mail()
{
    $mails = Joinus::pluck('email')->toArray();
    foreach ($mails as $mail)
    {
        Mail::to($mail)->send((new SendMail(new Joinus($mail)))->delay(30));

    };

}
```

Comment: Add some description to the answer explaining the issue and the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
public function send_mail()
{
    $mails = Joinus::all();
    $array = array();
    $allmails = array();
    foreach ($mails as $mail)
    {
        $allmails = array_push($array, $mail->email);

    };
    Mail::to($allmails)->send(new SendMail(new Joinus('email')))->delay(30);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks. But this is not about the brackets.